# 2D "World" to screen conversion

Tags: c++, math, opengl, rendering

I want to plot some Complex numbers in C++.
They reach from (-2 + -2i) to (2+2i).
My Screen is 1280 / 720.

Currently, this is how I translate the points:

```cpp
int offset = WIDTH / 2 - map(0, xMin, xMax, 0, WIDTH * AR);
int x = map(real, xMin, xMax, 0, WIDTH * AR) + offset;
int y = map(imag, iMin, iMax, HEIGHT, 0);
```

with:

```cpp
long double map(long double x, long double in_min, long double in_max, long double out_min, long double out_max)
{
    return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

and:

```
constexpr int WIDTH = 1280;
constexpr int HEIGHT = 720;
constexpr float AR = (float)HEIGHT / WIDTH;
```

It works, but seems a bit complicated for just scaling and offsetting, so how would I do this "better"?

Comment: Why don't you use a tool such as gnuplot or MatPlotLib?

Comment: It doesn't look really complicated to me...

Comment: Your code seems fine, maybe add a few comments and find a better function name for `map()`. Not sure what that `offset` is about, maybe add a comment there.

Comment: A `glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1)` + `glVertex2f(complex.real, complex.imaginary)` didn't work for some reason?

Comment: @genpfault: OP tries to keep the aspect ratio, ie "fit" the `[-2,2]x[-2,2]` square within the screen so it still stays a square.